# Is there operator AS (like in sql) in grails createria?

Tags: hibernate, grails

I want to rewrite this query to grails createria:

```
 String query = "SELECT * FROM Cars as ca WHERE ca.body = :bodies AND car.modelYeas > :data AND " +
                    "IF (ca.brend = 'Opel', " +
                        "exists (select Hood from Parts as p where p.number = ca.number AND ..., " +
                        "select Hood from Parts as p where p.wheel = ca.wheel AND ..., " +
                    ")"
```

Comment: "Is there operator AS (like in sql) in grails createria?" - Are you wanting to use the Hibernate Criteria Builder provided by GORM or the Detached Criteria api provided by GORM ?

Comment: provided by GORM

Comment: "provided by GORM" - GORM provides  more than 1.  Are you wanting to use the one that uses Detached Criteria or the Hibernate Criteria?  See https://gorm.grails.org/7.2.2/hibernate/manual/index.html#criteria vs https://gorm.grails.org/7.2.2/hibernate/manual/index.html#detachedCriteria.

Comment: Thanks for comment, I found that I can use this in criteria for example:   eqProperty('brand', 'this.brand').

Comment: "I found that I can use this in criteria for example: eqProperty" - That may mean you are using the Detached Criteria.  If you have solved the issue, it would be good to post that as an answer and accept it, for the benefit of the community who finds your question later.  Thank you for all the info!